# Bad characters in output from rss feed

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I am using the following method to connect to an rss feed.

```
var url = "http://blogs.mysite.com/feed/";
var sourceXmlFeed = "";

using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");
    sourceXmlFeed = wc.DownloadString(url);
}

var xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
xrs.CheckCharacters = false;

var xtr = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(sourceXmlFeed));

var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xtr, xrs);

SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);
```

However I am getting bad characters (as below) in the output and I assume it is something to do with the encoding.

eg. **for 2015 we are â?ogoing for goldâ?**

Anyone know how to fix this?

By the way, I am doing things this way because I have been unable to use a more direct approach (as below) without causing **The remote server returned an error: (443).**

```
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://blogs.mysite.com/feed);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with encoding is caused by reading xml as string because encoding detection in XML differs from encoding detection in strings.

```
WebClient webClient = null;
XmlReader xmlReader = null;

try
{
   webClient = new WebClient();
   webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");

   xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(webClient.OpenRead(url));

   // Read XML here because in a finaly block the response stream and the reader will be closed.
}
finally
{
   if (webClient != null)
   { webClient.Dispose(); }

   if (xmlReader != null)
   { xmlReader .Dispose(); }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this code I get the same error - The remote server returned an error: (443). Its good code but there is an issue with this feed

Comment: I tested my code again and it works (comment was replaced by `while (xmlReader.Read()) { Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value); }`). Are you sure you provide user agent in headers? Without it the site returns error 443.

Comment: Yes was adding headers but have not yet tried 'while reader.read'. I was using syndicationfeed.load. Will try again.

Comment: This does in fact work - while (xmlReader.Read()) { Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value); }). However I want to load an xml document into syndicationFeed.Load which strongly types elements of the rss feed. How can I instantiate an xmldocument from the xmlReader.Read method

Comment: Just use `SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);` instead of `while (xmlReader.Read()) { \* ... *\ }`. If this does not work show implementation of the SyndicationFeed.Load method.

Comment: Yes this worked.  Funny I thought I had tried that.  Must have missed something out